# xml data POST from file

Tags: c#, post

i am trying to send xml data from file to sensor what should get XML and make a values from that. I have this code, but i don't know if it is actually working.

I do have response from server but does it actually get those data from xml file? I am still newbie so i still don't know.

Thank you for any help..

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.254.20:5050/token");
        request.Method = "POST";

        string postData = @"C:\Users\lvrabel\Desktop\Crajsons\finals\Output.xml";
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

        request.ContentType = "application/xml";
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

        Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
        Console.WriteLine(postData);
        Console.ReadKey();

        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: So `responseFromServer` does contain the xml? If so. Hete are some options: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/querying-an-xdocument-vs-querying-an-xelement

Comment: @ZorgoZ No no, I have xml on my local pc, I need to POST it to the service on ip 192.168.254.20 where I have GET service.. If I am answering bad then i don't get your question, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read your xml file then you can convert it to bytes and then you can post it to server.

```
byte[] xmlData= File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\lvrabel\Desktop\Crajsons\finals\Output.xml");
```

Comment: Yes i though that i have that bad.. I tried that but I still don't see any data on IP. I think that code is good, but there is some bad communication between, even though i am getting 'OK' Response

Comment: may be there would be some issue on your service end.

Answer (score 0):

This is an other approach:

```
var xmlFile = @"C:\Users\lvrabel\Desktop\Crajsons\finals\Output.xml";
var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("http://192.168.254.20:5050/")};

using(var content = new StringContent(File.ReadAllText(xmlFile), Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml"))
{
    var result = await client.PostAsync("token", content);

    var respnseText = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); 
}
```

(Note: if you are accessing the same service endpoint with the same settings multiple times you can reuse the HttpClient instance to call the different service methods even across threads. This is why I have not wrapped it into a `using` clause)

If you have difficulties communicating with the service you might have other problems. If you don't get an exception then you can inspect the properties of the result to see if the service endpoint returned success (OK=200) or some other result code. You might find details about it. You could also simply reproduce this code in html+javascript, there you can more easily inspect the traffic in the browser. Of course, you could use some network sniffer, but that can be far more complicated.

[Update]
If you really only need to pass the file name as GET parameter, then use something like this:

```
var xmlFile = @"C:\Users\lvrabel\Desktop\Crajsons\finals\Output.xml";

var uri = new Uri($"http://192.168.254.20:5050/token?content={xmlFile}", UriKind.Absolute);
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var result = await client.GetAsync(uri);

    var respnseText = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that, but it seems that there is something wrong with that service. I already contacted their support so we'll see. I hope that i make it work. Also how do i try your code? It saying that it needs async method..

Comment: Well, you should go with async if you are dealing with IO, and networking is IO for sure :) From c# 7.1 on you can have async main also. Check this out: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/working-with-async-main-in-c-sharp-7-1/

Comment: Lets say that I need to add content into it for this syntax: http://192.168.254.20:5050/token?content=C:\Users\lvrabel\Desktop\Crajsons\finals\Output.xml 
Is there any chance how to add httpcontent?

Comment: That makes no sense to me. You can't reference something from client side (the file) this way and pass it to server side. You need to add it as contetn as I did. Or as your service requires, but that depends on the provider.

Comment: Aha, I understand. I think that i have something bad in code. When i put this normally in web browser http://192.168.254.20:5050/token?content=c:path it is working for me getting { "status": "Ok", "Matching Sensors": "1" }, But when i execute original code from my main question i still getting { "status": "Ok", "Matching Sensors": "0" }. I don't know how to solve this..

Comment: Then it means that you don't need the file contents just the name. It is quite unusual and smells like a huge security hole, but who knows. But if you can get this in the browser just by entering the url, it is not a POST, it is GET. Just open the developer tools in the browser switch to the network tab and do it again. You will see more there...